# Polymorphism Question

Tags: c++

For the sake of the question I've taken this code from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

```
class Polygon {
  protected:
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int a, int b)
      { width=a; height=b; }
};

class Rectangle: public Polygon {
  public:
    int area()
      { return width*height; }
};

class Triangle: public Polygon {
  public:
    int area()
      { return width*height/2; }
};

int main () {
  Rectangle rect;
  Triangle trgl;
  Polygon * ppoly1 = &rect;
  Polygon * ppoly2 = &trgl;
  ppoly1->set_values (4,5);
  ppoly2->set_values (4,5);
  return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to create a Polygon array and store Triangle and Rectangle objects in it and still be possible to access the functions associated with their respective classes?

For example:

```
Polygon *array[2];
array[0] = new Triangle;
array[1] = new Rectangle;
```

Is there any way to call area() from the Polygon array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the access to the functions is restricted to base class functions only.

But there's easy way to fix this problem, by providing pure virtual function in the base class:

```
class Polygon {
public:
  virtual int area()=0;
};
```

Then it'll just work fine.

Comment: That's a real bummer, I guess I'm going to have to think of a different way to structure my program.

Comment: Your example is almost exactly valid polymorphism example, except that Rectangle and Triangle are missing constructors with additional parameters.

Comment: @JacobBauer What's wrong with adding the pure virtual function? That's the only easy way to get runtime polymorphism, which is what you appear to be asking for.

Comment: So once I add a Triangle to the Polygon array it loses the area() function permanently?

Comment: that's why the prototype needs to be present in the base class and all Triangle functions need to have the same prototype as the functions in the base class.

Comment: In the original example, `Rectangle::area` and `Triangle::area` are completely unrelated to each other, and non-virtual.  In order for them to be related to each other, you need a common base class with a virtual method of the same name to tell the compiler to build the runtime table that makes polymorphism work.

Comment: @JacobBauer it still has the function, you just can't access it, *and* it's not the same function as `Rectangle`'s `area` function. Adding the function to the base class *as well* (it must be virtual, and it can optionally be pure virtual) is *the* solution - it does exactly what you want.